# Trying to run old makefile, "missing separator"

Tags: makefile

I've looked through the other posts similar to mine, which have been resolved by fixing a tab or spaces, but that didn't work for me (or I'm not looking in the right place). I'm trying to download the Swarm software, whose last stable release was in the early 2000s. Maybe this is a lost cause (or I might just have to suck it up and run this in a virtual machine) but I'm getting the error "Makefile.am:1: *** missing separator.  Stop." The first part of my makefile code is:

```
if USEBUILTINAVCALL
SUBDIRS = $(LIBOBJCDIR) avcall etc src tools java COM m4 tests
else
SUBDIRS = $(LIBOBJCDIR) etc src tools java COM m4 tests
endif

EXTRA_DIST = VERSION macosx/buildlibs.sh macosx/ChangeLog macosx/configure.sh macosx/INSTALL.MacOSX macosx/README.MacOSX macosx/swarm.xcode/project.pbxproj

SWARM_INSTALL = @SWARM_INSTALL@

install-data-local:
    $(mkinstalldirs) $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) swarmconfig.h $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) externvar.h $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)
    $(mkinstalldirs) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir) $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/swarm
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(top_builddir)/libtool $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/libtool-swarm
    if test $(SWARM_INSTALL) = install-sh; then $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(srcdir)/install-sh $(DESTDIR)$(bindir); fi

install-recursive: install-data-local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a `Makefile.in` file, not a `Makefile`.  That is, it's intended to be converted by **configure** or **automake**.

GNU make doesn't support an `if` statement (it has `ifdef` and `ifeq` and `ifneq`, but not `if`).  And tokens like `@SWARM_INSTALL@` are meant to be replaced.

Comment: You're right, it is a Makefile.in file. Do I understand you correctly in that I need to replace the @SWARM_INSTALL@ with a file path? And the code also says 
'# Makefile.in generated by automake 1.9.2 from Makefile.am.
# @configure_input@' what does that mean in terms of converting it? Would I have to run some command in terminal to do so?

Comment: You should run `./configure`.  That will convert `Makefile.in` to `Makefile`, among other things.  It will do this based on detecting the capabilities of your system.  After `./configure` is done, you will have a valid `Makefile` and you can run `make`.

Comment: You should have a `README` or `INSTALL` file that describes how to build the software.

Comment: Appreciate it - my code still isn't working due to other errors, but this answered my question